# WPGut - Updating failed and shortcode?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, block-editor, errors

I have a problem updating the WordPress page with custom created shortcode and inserted it?

Help, error status code:

`Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.`

Shortcode:

```
function register_form_template_f()
{ ?>
    <h1>Hello World! register</h1>
    <?php

}

add_shortcode('register_form_template', 'register_form_template_f');
```

Comment: What is WP Gut? Your shortcode is outputting directly to the browser which is very bad, **shortcodes must return their HTML as a string** yet there is no `return` statement in your function. By outputting directly to the browser with `<?php` tags your shortcode will cause lots of problems, such as appearing in the wrong order in content, breaking REST API endpoints used by the post editor, broken RSS feeds, broken nested shortcodes, etc

Answer (score 0):

As Tom pointed out, the reason you are seeing that error is you shortcode is not `return`ing your desired output, but rather outputting it right in place. This results in a breaking of the REST API and you seeing that error message.

Simple fix:

```php
function register_form_template_f() {
    return '<h1>Hello World! register</h1>';
}

add_shortcode('register_form_template', 'register_form_template_f');
```